# glDebugMessageCallback causes segfault

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-4

I'm in a bit of a catch-22 here. I can't debug my C++ OpenGL program because activating debug messages causes a segfault.

I have a debug callback function I register:

```
static void APIENTRY openglCallbackFunction(
  GLenum source,
  GLenum type,
  GLuint id,
  GLenum severity,
  GLsizei length,
  const GLchar* message,
  const void* userParam) {
  (void)source; (void)type; (void)id;
  (void)severity; (void)length; (void)userParam;
  fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", message);
  if (severity==GL_DEBUG_SEVERITY_HIGH) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Aborting...\n");
    abort();
  }
}
```

And I initiate the debug context in the following code:

```
this->window = glfwCreateWindow(this->winx, this->winy, "Cortex Stretcher", NULL, NULL);
  if(this->window == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window. If you have an Intel GPU, they are not 3.3 compatible. Try the 2.1 version of the tutorials.\n" );
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
  }
  glfwMakeContextCurrent(this->window);

  GLint flags; glGetIntegerv(GL_CONTEXT_FLAGS, &flags);
  if (flags & GL_CONTEXT_FLAG_DEBUG_BIT)
  {
     cout << "Debug output enabled!" << endl;
     glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT);
     glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT_SYNCHRONOUS);
     glDebugMessageCallback(openglCallbackFunction, nullptr);
    //  glDebugMessageControl(GL_DONT_CARE, GL_DONT_CARE, GL_DONT_CARE, 0, nullptr, GL_TRUE);
  }
```

If I merely comment out `glDebugMessageCallback(openglCallbackFunction, nullptr);` then my code runs without any errors (aside from my model rendering incorrectly which is why I'm trying to debug).

But if I try to register the callback, then my code segfaults (at registration). Any idea why? This is essentially just copy-pasted code.

Note: `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` returns 4.5.0 NVIDIA 375.39

Comment: `glDebugMessageCallback` is only available in OpenGL > 4.3. Your error message makes me think that you are either using OpenGL 3.3 or 2.1, which both don't support that.

Comment: That is not the case. If I print out `glGetString(GL_VERSION);` I get 4.5.0 NVIDIA 375.39. I'm using a Titan X.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What kind of GL loading mechanism are you using? Your code does create a context and makes it current, but you never load any GL function pointers. The typical `gl.h` header will only contain the GL functions up to GL 1.1, and those are also the only ones you can rely to be exported by your OpenGL library in a platform-independent manner. The fact that your compiler (and linker) does not complain about `glDebugMessageCallback` indicates that you use some GL loader like glew, glad, or whatever. These typically work by declaring a function pointer for every GL function, which are initalized to `NULL`, and will be loaded after you call some initialization function. Since you do no such thing before trying to set the debug callback, you are just calling a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: Ah, I am indeed using glew. I understand what it's doing now, but I didn't at the time I posted this question, and you're totally right, my debug setup is called before I initialize glew! Thank you!

Comment: I had shamefully sandwiched my debugging setup between GLFW and gl3w initialization steps. This solved my problem.